# How to properly implement a glass pane in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, progress, glasspane

I'm attempting to add a fancy [InfiniteProgressPanel](http://jroller.com/gfx/entry/wait_with_style_in_swing) as a GlassPane for my big Swing program. However, it does not appear. It looks similar to this:

```
...
InfiniteProgressPanel glassPane = new InfiniteProgressPanel();
setGlassPane(glassPane);
...
glassPane.start();
doSomeStuff();
glassPane.stop();
...
```

I believe it is running in the same thread as the long process it is meant to cover up. I'll admit, I don't know nearly enough about threads, and I should probably figure out how to run that InfiniteProgressPanel GlassPane in a separate thread, and the long process in its own thread, too.

Comment: Have you called `setVisible(true)` on the glasspane?

Comment: ...after you've set as the frames GlassPane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to:

- Run all long running code in a background thread. This is a must.

  > Sounds great! How do I do so? Encapsulate all of the long-running code inside of an .invokeLater method? And should that be SwingUtilities.invokeLater or EventQueue.invokeLater? And what's the difference, anyway?

  - No, by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MyRunnable)` you're doing exactly the opposite -- you're guaranteeing that the long-running code will be called **on** the Swing event thread -- the exact opposite of what you want. Instead use a SwingWorker's `doInBackground()` method to run the long-running code. Regarding your second point, there's no difference whatsoever between `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and `EventQueue.invokeLater`.
- Make most all Swing calls on the Swing event thread, also a **must**.

  > Fantastic! Again, how do I do so? Same thing as above?

  - By using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MyRunnable)` as noted above, or if you're using a SwingWorker then use its publish/process method pair as the SwingWorker tutorial will show you.
- Call `setVisible(true)` on your glass pane since per the JRootPane API, all glasspanes are by default invisible.

  > Romain Guy's InfiniteProgressPanel doesn't seem to need a setVisible(true). It appears when the InfiniteProgressPanel.start() method is called.

  - I am not familiar with this, do you have a link?

Comment: To each point: 1) Sounds great! How do I do so? Encapsulate all of the long-running code inside of an `.invokeLater` method? And should that be `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `EventQueue.invokeLater`? And what's the difference, anyway? 2) Fantastic! Again, how do I do so? Same thing as above? 3) Romain Guy's InfiniteProgressPanel doesn't seem to need a `setVisible(true)`. It appears when the `InfiniteProgressPanel.start()` method is called.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the concise answers to my questions. In regards to Romain Guy's [InfiniteProgressPanel](http://jroller.com/gfx/entry/wait_with_style_in_swing), see that link. He also had a post (on codeidol, I think), which went into more detail about IPP, but I am unable to find it now. And codeidol.com is down currently.

In the mean time, I will start doing more research on SwingWorker and how to properly use it with my ugly program. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, I already had an `.invokeLater` method call to my GUI, so that was taken care of. I was neglecting the `SwingWorker` class for my long-running processes. I now have them all in place. `glassPane.start();` is called right before `worker.execute();`, and the `.done()` method of that `SwingWorker` includes `glassPane.stop();`. Testing it out and it all seems to work! Yay! Thank you all so very much!

Answer (score 2):

Threads are different processes in the same program, per se.

In java, there are many different thread types, and the one you need for this job is `SwingWorker`.

The definition/use of this, from Oracle's docs, is:

> When a Swing program needs to execute a long-running task, it usually uses one of the worker threads, also known as the background threads. Each task running on a worker thread is represented by an instance of javax.swing.SwingWorker. SwingWorker itself is an abstract class; you must define a subclass in order to create a SwingWorker object; anonymous inner classes are often useful for creating very simple SwingWorker objects.

As you can see, this is what you need; a *background* thread.

---

```
final InfiniteProgressPanel glassPane;

...

class GlassPaneHandler extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
    @Override
   public String doInBackground() {
       glassPane.start();
       return setUpPaneAndStuff();
   }

    @Override
   protected void done() {
       try {
           glassPane.stop();
       } catch (Exception e) {  } //ignore
   }

   private void setUpPaneAndStuff() {
       //code
   }
}

...

(new GlassPaneHandler()).execute(); //place this in your code where you want to initiate the pane
```

---

for more see:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: This would assume that the glassPane.start doesn't interact with the UI in anyway...

Answer (score 1):

When you are updating a swing UI you need to do it in Swing's Event Thread.  This includes creation of components or any sort of progress updates.  You can do this via the [SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) method.

Therefore, you should create the glasspane and show it via the invokeLater if in a background thread.  Any progress updates to the glasspane from your long running process thread should be done via the invokeLater.